# Does Kubernetes K8s use multple server for load balancing?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod

Kubernetes will be using the same server or we can use multiple servers with k8s. if yes then how it will be work ?

In case of one instance full then would it create a new instance to route everything to the new server?

If anyone can show a real example of K8s then it would be great!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because he is asking if a bear is an animal.

Answer (score 3):

For this I can suggest [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io) to start reading from but briefly,

Kubernetes deals with resources or networking in the Master nodes (Control Plane).
Worker nodes simply have the kube-proxy and basic control mechanisms coming from kubelet service. You still can not control your cluster from worker nodes.

And yes K8s can use multiple servers for LoadBalancing. This is a **Possibility**.
When it comes to K8s you do not have to work in a single zone so therefore you do not have to have all the pods in the same server.

So, in a single zone if you have one master and multiple worker nodes you will be using Master's scheduler and LoadBalancer to manage the resources or the traffic if necessary. If you have multiple Master nodes, then you will be using Masters' schedulers and etc.

For a real example of K8s just search for Highly-Available Kubernetes Clusters and switch to Images section. You can have a visualized opinion about them that way.

I hope I was a little bit of help. But the docs could be more helpful I suppose.